# How to detect state of GPIO Pin in Python

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3

I'm currently searching for a possibility to get to know if there is power in a circuit with a Pin of the J8 Header (Pin 26). I bought a tutorial Book to a starter Kit and a huge Book about the raspberry Pi itself, but now I'm stuck. In both books they said it would be possible to detect by programming if there is a circuit running between a Pin and GND. How to do that, I've got no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the GPIO.  If there is a high voltage (3V3) it will read 1, if there is a low voltage (ground, 0V) it will read 0.

Pin 26 is (Broadcom) GPIO 7.

Ensure that you do not feed a voltage greater then 3V3 into a Pi GPIO.  You will likely damage the GPIO and/or the Pi itself.

There are several Python GPIO libraries.

See http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples#Python

Comment: Just like this: `GPIO.read(26)`? Will this return 1 or 0?

Comment: Yes, 1 or 0 will be returned (assuming read is the correct method for the library you want to use).

Comment: AttributeError: module 'RPi.GPIO' has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 3):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setup(26, 'output')

# Switch on
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)

# To read the state
state = GPIO.input(26)
if state:
   print('on')
else:
   print('off')
```

Comment: I get the error : `RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel firstRuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel first`

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work, but it might be the version, for python 2.6 or 3 this is working

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)

state = GPIO.input(26)
if state:
   print('on')
else:
   print('off')
```